# Ошибка 105 DNS адрес кириллицей

Tags: dns

Здравствуйте.
Перестала отображаться страница форума.

```
Не удается получить доступ к сайту
Не удается найти DNS-адрес сервера форум.стенды-почтой.рф.
Выполните поиск по запросу форум стенды почтой рф в Google
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

В гугле нашел только исправление проблемы на стороне клиента.
Куда в первую очередь смотреть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае это однозначно проблема на стороне хостинга. Такое иногда бывает (особенно в домене "рф"). Рекомендую звонить хостеру. А получив доступ к сайту установить на его главной странице информер. К примеру - ping-admin.ru/free_uptime/ Чтобы вы могли в дальнейшем аргументировать перед руководством переход на более дорогого, но и более надёжного хостера.